# How to Sort a string within an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

```
for (j = 1; j < x; j++) 
{
    for (n = 1; n < x; n++) 
    {
        if (strcmp(info[n - 1].lname, info[n].lname) > 0) 
        {
        strcpy(t, info[n - 1].lname);
        strcpy(info[n - 1].lname, info[n].lname);
        strcpy(info[n].lname, t);
        }
    }
}


for (j=0; j < x; j++)
{
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("ID number: %d", info[j].ID);
        printf("\nName: %s %s", info[j].fname, info[j].lname);
        printf("\nClass: %d%s", info[j].form, info[j].classname);
        printf("\nSymptons: %s", info[j].symptom);
        printf("\nPrescription: %s", info[j].symadmin);
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

}
```

Good day all, I have been trying to get this to work for quite some now. I want to sort an array of string by last name. The thing is, the last name is sorted but the accompanying data such as ID, fname, class etc isn't sorted with the last name. i.e. Only the last name shifts position.

How can I correct this?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Can I see the implementation, rather than words, perhaps.

Comment: As you change last name you need to change other entries to corresponding last name also .

Comment: @ameyCU And how do I go about doing this sir?

Comment: If you have array in your structures and not pointers , _then you can directly assign struct variable to one another and swap them_ (_**but in case of pointers you need to do all mannually**_) .

Answer (score 1):

You must swap the **whole** struct:

```
if (strcmp(info[n - 1].lname, info[n].lname) > 0)
{
    Patient t;
    t = info[n - 1];
    info[n - 1] = info[n];
    info[n] = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are only swapping the last name. You need to swap everything else as well.

```
if (strcmp(info[n - 1].lname, info[n].lname) > 0) 
{
    //swap ID
    int idTemp = info[n - 1].ID;
    info[n - 1].ID = info[n].ID;
    info[n].ID = idTemp;

    //swap last name
    strcpy(t, info[n - 1].lname);
    strcpy(info[n - 1].lname, info[n].lname);
    strcpy(info[n].lname, t);

    //now swap first name
    strcpy(t, info[n - 1].fname);
    strcpy(info[n - 1].fname, info[n].fname);
    strcpy(info[n].fname, t);

    //now swap classname
    strcpy(t, info[n - 1].classname);
    strcpy(info[n - 1].classname, info[n].classname);
    strcpy(info[n].classname, t);

    //now swap symptom
    strcpy(t, info[n - 1].symptom);
    strcpy(info[n - 1].symptom, info[n].symptom);
    strcpy(info[n].symptom, t);

    //now swap sysadmin
    strcpy(t, info[n - 1].symadmin);
    strcpy(info[n - 1].symadmin, info[n].symadmin);
    strcpy(info[n].symadmin, t);
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying but when I try to implement it, I still don't achieve the desired output. could you please give an example as what to do exactly? Thanks in advance.